# DIV overlay Fade in using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying make an overlay be contained inside a div like in this website. I'm trying to achieve that responsive fade in on hover via JQuery.

http://www.unheap.com/

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="tile-item">
       <div class="tile-head text-center bg-red">
           <div class="tile-head-overlay text-center">
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">New</button>
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">View History</button>
           </div>
           <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></h1>                        
       </div>
       <div class="tile-content">
           ...
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tile-head-overlay {
  /*display:hidden;*/
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #403D3C;
}
```

Doesn't seem to cover the entire top div with this set up. I also have no idea how to call this via JQuery. All I know is that I have to use the FadeToggle() function of Jquery via Hover()

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Some examples: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/